# Format cells in gridview boundfield columns without use of hard-coded cell index numbers

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I'm wanting to know if there might be a better way to format cells in my gridview than my current technique. Gridview is bound to a collection class of EventItem objects. (various snippets follow):

```
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim dataItem As EventItem = TryCast(e.Row.DataItem, EventItem)  ' data object needs to be cast to our class
        e.Row.Cells(3).Text = UIF.showDate(dataItem.AcknowledgeDate)
        e.Row.Cells(4).Text = UIF.showDate(dataItem.LastCompletedDate)
```

It seems a shame to resort to explicit cell index numbers when the declarative part of the gridview already establishes the ordinal position for the bound data:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AcknowledgeDate" HeaderText="Acknowledged Date"  DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastCompletedDate" HeaderText="Last Completed Date" DataFormatString="{0:M/d/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
```

I'm using this function for avoiding an "empty" date displaying as "1/1/1900":

```
    Public Shared Function showDate(ByVal d As Date) As String
    ' without use of this function, a null date in SQL (stored as Nothing in the object), shows as 12:00:00am 
    If d = #1/1/1900# Then
        Return String.Empty
    Else
        Return d.ToString("d")  'using standard date and time format string of "short date" which is same as mm/dd/yyyy for en-US
    End If
End Function
```

Could Eval somehow be used in the declarative part of the gridview so that I could still "wrap" the date in the function call and remove the code dependent upon hardcoded cell numbers?

Finally, my business class object, EventItem, holds dates as dates, not strings, and they can be NULL in the SQL table:

```
Public Class EventItem
    Private _LastCompletedDate As Date
    Private _AcknowledgeDate As Date

Me.LastCompletedDate = If(IsDBNull(rdr("LastCompletedDate")), Nothing, rdr("LastCompletedDate"))

 Public Property LastCompletedDate() As Date
    Get
        Return _LastCompletedDate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        _LastCompletedDate = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote these functions years ago in C#.  I used an online code converter to make them VB.

```
' ---- GetCellByName ----------------------------------
'
' pass in a GridViewRow and a database column name 
' returns a DataControlFieldCell or null

Public Shared Function GetCellByName(Row As GridViewRow, CellName As [String]) As DataControlFieldCell
    For Each Cell As DataControlFieldCell In Row.Cells
        If Cell.ContainingField.ToString() = CellName Then
            Return Cell
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function

' ---- GetColumnIndexByHeaderText ----------------------------------
'
' pass in a GridView and a Column's Header Text
' returns index of the column if found 
' returns -1 if not found 

Public Shared Function GetColumnIndexByHeaderText(aGridView As GridView, ColumnText As [String]) As Integer
    Dim Cell As TableCell
    For Index As Integer = 0 To aGridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1
        Cell = aGridView.HeaderRow.Cells(Index)
        If Cell.Text.ToString() = ColumnText Then
            Return Index
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function

' ---- GetColumnIndexByDBName ----------------------------------
'
' pass in a GridView and a database field name
' returns index of the bound column if found 
' returns -1 if not found 

Public Shared Function GetColumnIndexByDBName(aGridView As GridView, ColumnText As [String]) As Integer
    Dim DataColumn As System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField

    For Index As Integer = 0 To aGridView.Columns.Count - 1
        DataColumn = TryCast(aGridView.Columns(Index), System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField)

        If DataColumn IsNot Nothing Then
            If DataColumn.DataField = ColumnText Then
                Return Index
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return -1
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. Looks very good. Different approach than I was imagining possible. I was hoping to be able to exploit the natural ordinal position of the Boundfields in the Gridview. I've seen Eval used there but can't see how to do it.